# Error Running TensorFlow Serving from Dockerfile

Tags: docker, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I am working on a container to run TensorFlow Serving.

Here is my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM tensorflow/serving:latest

WORKDIR /

COPY models.config /models/models.config
COPY models/mnist /models/mnist
```

Here is my `models.config` for a simple `mnist` model:

```
model_config_list {
    config: {
        name: "mnist",
        base_path: "/models/mnist"
        model_platform: "tensorflow"
        model_version_policy {
            specific {
                versions: 1646266834
            }
        }
        version_labels {
            key: 'stable'
            value: 1646266834
        }
    }
}
```

The `models` directory is setup as follows:

```
$ ls -Rls models
total 0
0 drwxr-xr-x  3 david  staff  96 Mar  2 16:21 mnist

models/mnist:
total 0
0 drwxr-xr-x  6 david  staff  192 Mar  2 16:21 1646266834

models/mnist/1646266834:
total 304
  0 drwxr-xr-x  2 david  staff      64 Mar  2 16:21 assets
 32 -rw-r--r--  1 david  staff   15873 Mar  2 16:20 keras_metadata.pb
272 -rw-r--r--  1 david  staff  138167 Mar  2 16:20 saved_model.pb
  0 drwxr-xr-x  4 david  staff     128 Mar  2 16:21 variables

models/mnist/1646266834/assets:
total 0

models/mnist/1646266834/variables:
total 1424
1416 -rw-r--r--  1 david  staff  722959 Mar  2 16:20 variables.data-00000-of-00001
   8 -rw-r--r--  1 david  staff    2262 Mar  2 16:20 variables.index
```

The problem is that when I build and run my container, I receive an error.

```
$ docker build -t example.com/example-tf-serving:1.0 .
$ docker run -it -p 8500:8500 -p 8501:8501 --name example-tf-serving --rm example.com/example-tf-serving:1.0
```

The error is as follows `Not found: /models/model`:

```
2022-03-03 00:48:06.242923: I tensorflow_serving/model_servers/server.cc:89] Building single TensorFlow model file config:  model_name: model model_base_path: /models/model
2022-03-03 00:48:06.243215: I tensorflow_serving/model_servers/server_core.cc:465] Adding/updating models.
2022-03-03 00:48:06.243254: I tensorflow_serving/model_servers/server_core.cc:591]  (Re-)adding model: model
2022-03-03 00:48:06.243899: E tensorflow_serving/sources/storage_path/file_system_storage_path_source.cc:365] FileSystemStoragePathSource encountered a filesystem access error: Could not find base path /models/model for servable model with error Not found: /models/model not found
```

How do I fix my `Dockerfile` so that the above command will work?

For this solution, the quick and easy way will not work for me, so I cannot accept it as a solution:

```
docker run --name=the_name -p 9000:9000 -it -v "/path_to_the_model_in_computer:/path_to_model_in_docker" tensorflow/serving:1.15.0 --model_name=MODEL_NAME --port=9000
```

Comment: Could you try adding `RUN mkdir -p /models/model` by any chance ?

Comment: Good question, it turns out that `/models/model` is just the default for a single model deployment. According to the documentation (https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/serving/serving_basic), this path is *supposed* to be configurable, but because of my deployment requirements, I cannot mount the volume on the command line as part of the `docker run` command, and I must do it via the `Dockerfile` and run this all as a single `docker run` command as described above: `$ docker run -it -p 8500:8500 -p 8501:8501 --name example-tf-serving --rm example.com/example-tf-serving:1.0`

Comment: And could you add this folder creation inside your dockerfile in order to move forward and maybe have another error since the current one is due to this folder being inexistant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/serving/docker

> Optional environment variable MODEL_NAME (defaults to model)
>
> Optional environment variable MODEL_BASE_PATH (defaults to /models)

You are using default values of these env variables, so Tensorflow is trying to find model in `/models/model`. You have different model path in the container, so `/models/model not found` is correct.

I would say simple configuration of `MODEL_NAME` env variable should solve the problem:

```
$ docker run -it -p 8500:8500 -p 8501:8501 \
  --name example-tf-serving \
  -e MODEL_NAME=mnist \
  --rm example.com/example-tf-serving:1.0
```

For `multiple models` https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/serving/serving_config#model_server_configuration

> The easiest way to serve a model is to provide the --model_name and --model_base_path flags (or setting the MODEL_NAME environment variable if using Docker). However, if you would like to serve multiple models, or configure options like polling frequency for new versions, you may do so by writing a Model Server config file.
>
> You may provide this configuration file using the --model_config_file flag and instruct Tensorflow Serving to periodically poll for updated versions of this configuration file at the specifed path by setting the --model_config_file_poll_wait_seconds flag.

See docker doc: https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/serving/docker#passing_additional_arguments

You need to set `CMD` in the Dockerfile (so you don't need to specify it in run time, because requirement is to use only Dockerfile), e.g.:

```
FROM tensorflow/serving:latest

WORKDIR /

COPY models.config /models/models.config
COPY models/mnist /models/mnist

CMD ["--model_config_file=/models/models.config"]
```

Comment: Thanks Jan. One thing, I need to put this in my Dockerfile and specify the model config with multiple models. How do I do this inside my Dockerfile?

Comment: I need the advanced multiple model config and specify it only in the Dockerfile, which is why this question is challenging! https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/serving/serving_config

Comment: @mobiusinversion see update

Comment: By the way, for anyone visiting this later and trying to run the example in the question, also another flag is needed for the supplied models.config: `CMD ["--model_config_file=/models/models.config", "--allow_version_labels_for_unavailable_models=true"]`